# Typescript: how to handle typing when leaving current page (never type)?

Tags: typescript

I have some kind of code like this in a React SPA

```js
export const handleLogin = async (authData: AuthData): Promise<CurrentUser> => {
  const { userType } = await authenticate(authData);
  if (userType !== 'client') {
    return redirectTo("www.google.com");
  } else {
    const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();
    return currentUser;
  }
};
```

In the case of a redirect, we are actually leaving the SPA and navigating to an external page so actually the JS code should stop executing (I don't want `handleLogin` to resolve, because in such case no currentUser would be returned).

Not sure exactly how to type this redirect thing. I'm trying to use `never` but my code is hacky:

```
export const redirectTo = async (url: string): Promise<never> => {
  window.location.href = url;
  await delayPromise(10000);
  throw new Error(`unexpected redirection failure to ${url}`);
};
```

Can someone give me an elegant solution to this usecase?

Comment: Your code is just fine. Personally I'd use `await redirectTo` instead of `return redirectTo` but it's a detail.

Comment: @paleo thanks. That detail is due to eslint complaining :D

Comment: Eslint is wrong. If you decide to surround the code in `handleLoging` with a `try catch`, then an exception in `redirectTo` wouldn't be catched and would be still returned as a rejected promise.